# How to discover wifi direct services on android using the SERVICE_TYPE_ALL protocol type?

Tags: android

I am attempting to set my application up to use wifi direct service discovery to discover all wifi direct services that are being advertised. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
void discoverAllServices() {

   manager.setServiceResponsListener(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ServiceResponseListener() {

       @Override
       public void onServiceAvailable(int protocolType, byte[] responseData, 
                                                     WifiP2pDevice srcDevice) {

           Log.d(TAG, "ProtocolType -> " + protocolType);
       }
   });

   serviceRequestForAll = WifiP2pServiceRequest.newInstance(WifiP2pServiceInfo.SERVICE_TYPE_ALL);

   manager.addServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequestForAll, new ActionListener() {

       @Override
       public void onSuccess() {
           Log.d(TAG, "Added service all discovery request");
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(int arg0) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Failed adding service all discovery request");
       }      
  });

  manager.discoverServices(channel, new ActionListener() {

       @Override
       public void onSuccess() {
           Log.d(TAG, "ServiceAll discovery initiated");
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(int arg0) {
           Log.d(TAG, "ServiceAll discovery failed");
       }      
  });
}
```

I get a success on adding the service request and a success on the discoverServices() call. But no services are discovered. When I have wifi direct services advertising nearby. What do I need to do in order to discover the wifi direct services that are being advertised.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of...

1) Make sure you initialize the manager. 
2) Make sure that you have the proper permissions declared in the manifest.